# Grid data-structure and placement algorithm for my Battleships implementation?

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to make my own version of the game Battleships (in German: Schiffe versenken).

I have made the game board as a 10x10 dataframe. The coordinates of the ships are created randomly. I have 4 different kinds of ships with lengths between 5 an 2. Each of these ships is a list. The elements of the list are made of the randomly created starting coordinates `(ship_row, ship_col)` and depending if the ship is horizontal or vertical the other elements are either `ship_row + n` or `ship_col + n`.

Problem: it can happen that the length of a ship exceeds the bounds of the dataframe. How can I set boundaries for those ship lists and how can I make a loop to create a new ship list if the first made one exceeds the boundaries?

Here my Code for the example ship Schlachtschiff:

```
board = []

for n in range (10):
    board.append(['O'] * 10)

board = pd.DataFrame(board)

g = rd.randint(1, 2)
random_row(board)
random_col(board)
ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)

for Schlachtschiff in board:
    if g == 1:
        Schlachtschiff = [(ship_row, ship_col),
                          (ship_row, ship_col + 1),
                          (ship_row, ship_col + 2),
                          (ship_row, ship_col + 3),
                          (ship_row, ship_col + 4)]
    else:
        Schlachtschiff = [(ship_row, ship_col),
                          (ship_row + 1, ship_col),
                          (ship_row + 2, ship_col),
                          (ship_row + 3, ship_col),
                          (ship_row + 4, ship_col)]
```

I tried to solve it with a `while` loop by looking at the last element of the created list, but that would not stop:

```
while Schlachtschiff[-1] not in board:
    if g == 1:
        Schlachtschiff = [(ship_row, ship_col),
                          (ship_row, ship_col + 1),
                          (ship_row, ship_col + 2),
                          (ship_row, ship_col + 3),
                          (ship_row, ship_col + 4)]
    else:
        Schlachtschiff = [(ship_row, ship_col),
                          (ship_row + 1, ship_col),
                          (ship_row + 2, ship_col),
                          (ship_row + 3, ship_col),
                          (ship_row + 4, ship_col)]

    if Schlachtschiff[-1] in board:
        break
```

To stop the ships from overlapping I wrote this code (Note "Kreuzer is the second kind of ship, being created the same way as above):

```
for i in Schlachtschiff:
    for j in Kreuzer:
        if i == j:
            random_row(board)
            random_col(board)
            ship_row_1 = random_row(board)
            ship_col_1 = random_col(board)
            g = rd.randint(1, 2)

            if g == 1:
                Kreuzer = [(ship_row, ship_col),
                           (ship_row, ship_col + 1),
                           (ship_row, ship_col + 2)]
            else:
                Kreuzer = [(ship_row, ship_col),
                           (ship_row + 1, ship_col),
                           (ship_row + 2, ship_col)]
```

Now I dont have that problem anymore thanks to help of @smci. My code looks as follows now:

```
board = []
board = pd.DataFrame(data='□', index=range(1, 10 + 1),
```

columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
print(board)

```
def random_row(board):
    return rd.randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
     return rd.randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def Schiff_erstellen(Schiff, Start, Stop):
    g = rd.randint(1, 2)
    random_row(board)
    random_col(board)
    ship_row = random_row(board)
    ship_col = random_col(board)
    Schiff = [(ship_row, ship_col)]
    while Schiff[-1] > (ship_row_probe, ship_col_probe):
        g = rd.randint(1, 2)
        random_row(board)
        random_col(board)
        ship_row = random_row(board)
        ship_col = random_col(board)
        Schiff=[(ship_row, ship_col)]
        if g == 1:
            for i in range(Start, Stop):
                Schiff.append((ship_row, ship_col + i))
        else:
            for i in range(Start, Stop):
                Schiff.append((ship_row + i, ship_col))
        if Schiff[-1] <= (ship_row_probe, ship_col_probe):
            break

    return Schiff
```

Comment: How have you tried to do it so far?

Comment: I tried it with for Loop, but that did not worked out and I also tried it with a while loop, to control it in the next step, but it did not stop.

Comment: @R.Abdi welcome to SO :) Can you please post the code that didn't work and say what the problems were?

Comment: Please edit the post, don't leave this sort of stuff in comments.  There is an edit button below the post

Comment: This is much more complex than you think. You also need to work out how to stop the battleships overlapping.

Comment: I figuered that one out....sort of

Comment: It will be much easier if you store the ships directly on the cells of the `board`, e.g.  'K','K','K','K' in adjacent cells. Instead of creating a custom data-structure of coords for each ship. It will also be easier to look up enemy attacks against a cell.

Comment: Also don't create two boards: `board` and then a copy `board_1 = pd.DataFrame(board)`. Just create and initialize an empty `pd.DataFrame()`.

Comment: I can't do this, because I want to hide the ships. They should not be visible on the board. I am only trying half of the game, where the Player should find the hidden ships by guessing the coordinates. I don't know, if you know the Code Academy Version, but I wanted to do something like that, only with longer and diverse ships. If I understood you right :D

Comment: With `board = pd.DataFrame(data='□', index=range(1,10+1), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))`. That character is Unicode for empty square.

Comment: Yes you can do it with one board. You just create a method `display(show_ships=False)` or whatever, that take a boolean flag, default to False. Alternatively, keep two parallel boards, and update them both as needed.

Comment: @ekhumoro: directly using the board makes the overlap check simple. Also, place the longest ships first.

Comment: FYI this is borderline code-review type question (since your choice of data structures is causing the problem). Take a look at CodeReview.SE, there are [45 Battleships questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=battleships+is%3Aq)

Comment: thank you very much for your help ! Since I don't have time today anymore to work on the project, I am going to try your tips tomorrow ! And also thank you for the link to the battleship questions.

Comment: @smci. I didn't claim that it is complex in any *absolute* sense: just that it is more complex than the OP seems to think it is (judging by the current state of the question).

Comment: @R.Abdi: sure. Sadly I couldn't find a pandas implementation of Battleships anywhere, but trust me, keeping all the data on one(/two) grids, inserting letters for ship placement, then looking it up with pandas `board.ix[row,col]`, will make your life simple.

Comment: @R.Abdi: I do suggest you put "for my Battleships implementation" in the title, since your choice of data-structure may be a list, list-of-lists, numpy array, pandas dataframe etc. And if you want to place a length-5 ship on a 10x10 grid (numbered 1..10 instead of 0..9), then for horizontal placement your leftmost square can be anywhere from col=1..6. Really your issue is constraining the random selection of placement square, to give legal placement. Not "constraining the list".

Comment: @smci : It works !!! Thank you so much :D Suddenly my code became much short

Comment: If you figured out the answer to your own question, post it as an answer and then accept it, so other people can see how you solved it (rather than editing it into the question itself).

Answer (score 1):

First let's take a look at placing a single ship. A ship is a line segment, so you need three random numbers to characterize it: a boolean direction (horizontal or vertical), and the coordinates of the upper left-hand corner. I'm assuming that for any given ship, the length is fixed. Now if you know the length is `L` and the board is `M`x`N`, you can restrict the positions like this:

```
def generate_ship(L, M, N):
    """ Returns the slices to fill in on an MxN board to get a random L-sized ship """
    # True = vertical
    direction = random.randrange(2)
    rsize = direction * (L - 1)
    csize = (not direction) * (L - 1)
    row = random.randrange(M - rsize)
    col = random.randrange(N - csize)
    return slice(row, row + 1 + rsize), slice(col, col + 1 + csize)
```

Multiplying by `direction` and `not direction` saves you the trouble of having to use `if` statements to handle the different cases. You can use the result of this function directly with `df.iloc`, since it's a tuple of slices:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
from string import ascii_uppercase

M = N = 10
df = pd.DataFrame(np.tile([[' ']], [M, N]), index=np.arange(M), columns=list(ascii_uppercase[:N]))
df.iloc[generate_ship(3, M, N)] = 'O'
```

So far so good, but now you want to generate multiple non-overlapping ships. The simplest method is brute-force: start with the largest ship and keep generating a new ship until you get one that doesn't overlap:

```
M = N = 10
df = pd.DataFrame(np.tile([[' ']], [M, N]), index=np.arange(M), columns=list(ascii_uppercase[:N]))
for L in (5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2):
    while True:
        ship = generate_ship(L, M, N)
        if (df.iloc[ship] == ' ').all():
            df.iloc[ship] = 'O'
            break
```

A much more deterministic approach would be to maintain a grid of available coordinates and prune it every time you generate a ship. You could, for example, maintain an 2xMxN array recording the largest ship that can be placed at a given location. Every time you place a ship you would update this array. To generate, you would simply select from locations available via something like `np.argwhere(options[direction] >= L)`:

```
class ShipGenerator:
    def __init__(self, M, N):
        horiz = np.arange(N, 0, -1)[None, :].repeat(M, axis=0)
        vert = np.arange(M, 0, -1)[:, None].repeat(N, axis=1)
        self.options = np.stack((horiz, vert), axis=0)

    def generate_ship(self, L):
        options = np.argwhere(self.options >= L)
        n = len(options)
        if n == 0:
            raise ValueError(f'Unable to generate ship of size {L}. '
                             f'Max remaining space is {self.options.max(None)}')

        direction, row, col = options[random.randrange(len(options))]
        row_end = row + 1 + direction * (L - 1)
        col_end = col + 1 + (not direction) * (L - 1)

        self.clear_region(row, row_end, col, col_end)
        return (slice(row, row_end), slice(col, col_end))

    def clear_region(self, r_start, r_end, c_start, c_end, margin=0):
        """ Once a ship has been generated, update the map to restrict squared around it """
        r_start = max(r_start - margin, 0)
        c_start = max(c_start - margin, 0)
        r_end = min(r_end + margin, self.options.shape[1])
        c_end = min(c_end + margin, self.options.shape[2])

        # Update ship + margin
        self.options[:, r_start:r_end, c_start:c_end] = 0

        # Update horizontal restrictions
        self.options[0, r_start:r_end, :c_start] = \
            np.minimum(self.options[0, r_start:r_end, :c_start],
                       np.arange(c_start, 0, -1))

        # Update vertical restrictions
        self.options[1, :r_start, c_start:c_end] = \
            np.minimum(self.options[1, :r_start, c_start:c_end],
                       np.arange(r_start, 0, -1)[:, None])
```

Generating a board now becomes that much simpler:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.tile([[' ']], [M, N]), index=np.arange(M), columns=list(ascii_uppercase[:N]))
generator = ShipGenerator(M, N)
for L in (5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2):
    df.iloc[generator.generate_ship(L)] = 'O'
```

You would want to maintain a board to record enemy hits, but also metadata for the individual ships. Storing metadata on the board would be wasteful. Instead, you can create a `Ship` object that contains the metadata, including the slices made by `generate_ship`. The board then becomes a set of labels that are indices into a list of `Ship`s.